# JavaScript Date/Time Formatting

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

I am needing to convert the standard Date(); JS object to the following format:
7/13/2021 8:47:58 PM
(M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z)

I'm struggling to get this EXACT format in the simplest way possible. This is what I have so far:

```js
var d = new Date,
    dformat = [d.getMonth()+1,
               d.getDate(),
               d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
              [d.getHours(),
               d.getMinutes(),
               d.getSeconds()].join(':');

console.log(dformat);
```

I am struggling to get the time zone, which I am conjecturing adds the AM/PM (I could very well be mistaken).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: AM/PM has nothing to do with time zone, just whether the time is before or after noon.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - that post is definitely helpful for being able to see a high level overview of all of the options - I really appreciate that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thank you Shivam!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var d = new Date,
        dformat = [d.getMonth()+1,
                   d.getDate(),
                   d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
                  d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')

    console.log(dformat);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Because `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US').replace(',', '')` is not enough code? ;-)